# Form does not validate inputs

Tags: javascript, html, validation, calculator

I am trying to get this values to validate but for some reason it does not validate them and it calculates them regardless. I'm really confused and am lost on what to do. Everything else calculates fine. This is a calculator.
I am trying to get this values to validate but for some reason it does not validate them and it calculates them regardless. I'm really confused and am lost on what to do. Everything else calculates fine. This is a calculator.

```js
var bmr = 0;

function validateForm() 
{
  var age = document.forms["calcBMR"]["age"].value;
  var height = document.forms["calcBMR"]["weight"].value;
  var weight = document.forms["calcBMR"]["height"].value;

  if (age == "") 
  {
    alert("Age must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  
  if (height == "") 
  {
    alert("Height must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  
  if (weight == "") 
  {
    alert("Height must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
 
    
}

function calc() {
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
  var activeLevel = document.getElementById("activeLevel").value;
 
  switch(activeLevel)
    {
      case "sedentary":
        
      if(gender == "male")
      {
        bmr = 88.362 + ( 13.397 * weight ) + ( 4.799 * height )-( 5.677 * age );
        bmr = bmr * 1.2;
      }
      else
      {
        bmr = 447.593 + ( 9.247 * weight ) + ( 3.098 * height ) - ( 4.330 * age );
        bmr = bmr * 1.2;
      }
      return bmr;
      case "lightActive":
        if(gender == "male")
        {
          bmr = 88.362 + ( 13.397 * weight ) + ( 4.799 * height )-( 5.677 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.375;
        }
        else
        {
          bmr = 447.593 + ( 9.247 * weight ) + ( 3.098 * height ) - ( 4.330 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.375;
        }
        return bmr;

      case "moderateActive":
        if(gender == "male")
        {
          bmr = 88.362 + ( 13.397 * weight ) + ( 4.799 * height )-( 5.677 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.55;
        }
        else
        {
          bmr = 447.593 + ( 9.247 * weight ) + ( 3.098 * height ) - ( 4.330 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.55;
        }
        return bmr;

      case "veryActive":
        if(gender == "male")
        {
          bmr = 88.362 + ( 13.397 * weight ) + ( 4.799 * height )-( 5.677 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.725;
        }
        else
        {
          bmr = 447.593 + ( 9.247 * weight ) + ( 3.098 * height ) - ( 4.330 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.725;
        }
        return bmr;

      case "extraActive":
        if(gender == "male")
        {
          bmr = 88.362 + ( 13.397 * weight ) + ( 4.799 * height )-( 5.677 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.9;
        }
        else
        {
          bmr = 447.593 + ( 9.247 * weight ) + ( 3.098 * height ) - ( 4.330 * age );
          bmr = bmr * 1.9;
        }
        return bmr;
      
      default:
        if(gender == "male")
        {
          bmr = 88.362 + ( 13.397 * weight ) + ( 4.799 * height )-( 5.677 * age );
        
        }
        else
        {
          bmr = 447.593 + ( 9.247 * weight ) + ( 3.098 * height ) - ( 4.330 * age );
        
        }
        return bmr;
      }  
}


document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  calc();
  document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = bmr;

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assignment1.css">    

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <title>Assignment 1 - BMR Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
  
   <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="module-border-wrap"><div class="module">
    <header>
      
      <h1>BMR Calculator</h1>
    </div></div>
    </header>
    <br><h4><strong>What is BMR?:</strong></h4>
       Basal Metabolic Rate (BMR) is your metabolism rate. It calculates the total amount of calories you should be eating per day based on Age, Height, Weight, and Gender.<br><br>

    <h4><strong>BMR versus BMI:</strong></h4>
    <p>While both take similar calculations, both are very different. Body Mass Index (BMI) takes your height and weight. </p>


    

    <br><br><img src="images/weight scale.jpg" class="size1" alt="Scale">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="images/outside.gif" class="size2" alt="Pixel art forest"><br><br>

    <h3>Take a BMR test right here to find the number of calories you need per day:</h3><br><br>

    <div id="centre">
     <form action="#" name="calcBMR" >
        
      <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" required="required"> Male
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" required="required"> Female<br><br>

      <label for="age">How old are you?</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="age" name="age" value="age" min="0" required="required"><br><br>
       
      <label for="height">What is your height in centimetres? (cm):</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="height" name="height" value="height" min="0" required="required"><br><br>
        
      <label for="weight">What is your weight in kilograms? (kg):</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" value="weight" min="0" required="required"><br><br>
     
      <label for="activeLevel">What is your Activity Level?: </label><br>
      <select id="activeLevel" name="activeLevel">
        <option value="sedentary">Sedentary (Little to no Exercise)</option>
        <option value="lightActive">Lightly Active (Exercise 1-3 times per week)</option>
        <option value="moderateActive">Moderately Active (Exercise 3-5 times per week</option>
        <option value="veryActive">Very Active (Exercise everyday)</option>
        <option value="extraActive">Extremely Active (Professional Athlete)</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <input type="reset" name="Reset"><br><br>
    
    
    </form>
     
      
      <button type="button"
      onclick="">
      Result</button><br>
      
      <textarea id="lblResult">BMR</textarea><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      
    </div>
    <footer>
      <hr><br><br>
      <h5>&copy; Copyright Alim Kutchhi #301135845 - COMP125 - Summer 2021.</h5><br><br>
    </footer>
     <script src="Assignment1.js"></script>
  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets up `validateForm` as a callback? Also, you have several errors in your HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="Assignment1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assignment1.css">   
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
<title>Assignment 1 - BMR Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>     
<h1>BMR Calculator</h1>
</div></div>
</header>
<br><h4><strong>What is BMR?:</strong></h4>
Basal Metabolic Rate (BMR) is your metabolism rate. It calculates the total amount of calories you should be eating per day based on Age, Height, Weight, and Gender.<br><br>

<h4><strong>BMR versus BMI:</strong></h4>
<p>While both take similar calculations, both are very different. Body Mass Index (BMI) takes your height and weight. </p>
<br><br><img src="images/weight scale.jpg" class="size1" alt="Scale">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="images/outside.gif" class="size2" alt="Pixel art forest"><br><br>

<h3>Take a BMR test right here to find the number of calories you need per day:</h3><br><br>

<br>
<form name="getform" id="getform" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<select name="gender" id="gender">
<option value="male" selected>Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<br><br>
How old are you?
<br>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<br><br>
What is your height in centimetres? (cm):
<br>
<input type="text" id="height" name="height">
<br><br>
What is your weight in kilograms? (kg):
<br>
<input type="text" id="weight" name="weight">
<br><br>
What is your Activity Level?: 
<br>
<select id="activeLevel" name="activeLevel">
<option value="sedentary" selected>Sedentary (Little to no Exercise)</option>
<option value="lightActive">Lightly Active (Exercise 1-3 times per week)</option>
<option value="moderateActive">Moderately Active (Exercise 3-5 times per week</option>
<option value="veryActive">Very Active (Exercise everyday)</option>
<option value="extraActive">Extremely Active (Professional Athlete)</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button type="button" id="reset" onclick="resetAll();">Reset</button>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" id="result" onclick="getResult();">Result</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="result_text" name="result_text" disabled style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid black;" value="">
</form>

<footer>
<hr><br><br>
<h5>&copy; Copyright Alim Kutchhi #301135845 - COMP125 - Summer 2021.</h5><br><br>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function calc() {
var age = parseInt(document.getform.age.value);
var height = parseFloat(document.getform.height.value);
var weight = parseFloat(document.getform.weight.value);
var gender = document.getform.gender.value;
var activeLevel = document.getform.activeLevel.value;
var error = '';
var bmr;
if (isNaN(age)) {
error+='Age must be filled out.';
}
if (isNaN(height)) {
error+=' Height must be filled out.';
} 
if (isNaN(weight)) {
error+=' Weight must be filled out';
}
if (error) {
alert(error);
return;
}
if (gender = "male") {
bmr = (10*weight) + (6.5*height) - (5*age) +5;
} else if (gender="female") {
bmr = (10*weight) + (6.5*weight) - (5*age) -161;
}
if (activeLevel =="sedentary") {
tdee = bmr * 1.2;
return tdee;
} else if (activeLevel == "lightActive") {
tdee = bmr * 1.375;
return tdee;
} else if (activeLevel == "moderateActive") {
tdee = bmr * 1.55;
return tdee;
} else if (activeLevel == "veryActive") {
tdee = bmr * 1.725;
return tdee;
} else if (activeLevel == "extraActive") {
tdee = bmr * 1.9;
return tdee;
}
}
function getResult() {
calc();
document.getform.result_text.value = calc();
}
function resetAll() {
document.getform.age.value = "";
document.getform.height.value = "";
document.getform.weight.value = "";
document.getElementById("gender").selectedIndex = 0;
document.getElementById("activeLevel").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```